# How can I convert a string into a char with a length of four in C#?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I have an older SQL table that contains a field of Char(4).

I need to test this table by inserting a new row but the field should contain text.  (Edit) This is in C# Visual Studio Core inserting into a repository.
For example

```
 repo.Insert(new MyTable() { MyChar = Convert.ToChar("Self")});
```

I get the error

> System.FormatException: 'String must be exactly one character long.'

How can I insert a string into a SQL table that has a char(4) field in C#?

Comment: Why convert to Char??? Doesn't the DB take a string? (Just check the length and to control the content maybe pad as needed..)

Comment: char(4) means that the column have fixed length from 4 chars it is still string

Comment: The database might take the string but c# using entity framework core does not

Comment: You should make it into real question with good [MCVE] now when you figured an answer. Right now it makes no sense.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I think you need `.PadRight` *before* the call to `.Substring` to avoid an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if the string is less than `4` characters. Although I believe SQL will allow shorter strings and will pad the end automatically.

Comment: `repo.Insert(new MyTable { MyChar = "Self".PadRight(4).Substring(0, 4) });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue was with the entity model.  I needed to change the type

```
        [Column("inscode", TypeName = "char(4)")]
        public char InsCode { get; set; }
```

to

```
        [Column("inscode", TypeName = "char(4)")]
        public string InsCode { get; set; }
```

So the database is char(4) but the model sees it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert to char. Just insert the string.

Char(x) in SQL is a fixed length string.
Char in .NET is a single character.

Comment: To add: If you enter a single char into a char(4) in sql, it will add spaces to fill up as per SQL specifications.

Comment: Just inserting the string creates the error "Cannot convert type 'string' to 'char'"

Comment: @pldiguanaman is it `char` or `char[]`?

Comment: The field is a char with a length of four in the table.  When I hover over the field it indicates it is a char and not a char[]